# How should I phrase this sentence for accuracy?

Tags: word-choice

Have you ever had one of those days when you can not think of the right word or word usage in a sentence? Can someone help me with this one?

"We help each other reach his/her full potential". Each other and his/her do not seem to go together.

Thanks, 
D.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to a collective potential:

> We help each other reach our full potential.

If you are referring to each person's own respective potentials:

> We help each other reach their own full potential.